# url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.5 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1

Tags: flutter, dart

url_launcher_platform_interface ^1.0.5 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1 is required.
So, because canteen_food depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting a question, try to give more details. I believe you are using a package which is having a version conflict. My suggestion would be to go to url_launcher_platform_interface 's [git project](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_platform_interface), and check issues or report a bug in there.